# Font rendering Not working for Mozilla

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts, render

I want to render segoeuilight font. I am rendering it like this:-

```
/*Font Face*/
@font-face
{ font-family: 'SegoeUI-Light'; src: url('segoeuilight.eot'); src: url('segoeuilight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('segoeuilight.woff') format('woff'), url('segoeuilight.ttf') format('truetype'), url('segoeuilight.svg#segoeuilight') format('svg'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal }

@font-face
{ font-family: 'SegoeUI'; src: url('segoeui.eot'); src: url('segoeui.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('segoeui.woff') format('woff'), url('segoeui.ttf') format('truetype'), url('segoeui.svg#segoeui') format('svg'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; } 
/*---------*/
```

This is working fine on all the browsers but not rending the font for firfox. It gives an error for firefox :-
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - segoeuilight.woff"

I have placed this file and I can see this file on my location.
Need help to get it work on Firefox.

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft has copyright to the Segoe UI font family, and I don’t think you can legally use it as a downloadable font.

Answer (score 0):

You've added more than one `src` attribute to each of your declarations, because of that, the browser will take the last valid one. In your case it was the WOFF case, and so it tried to load it. Instead, you should comma separate your `src`s, so that you attempt to load the best (local e.g.) first, followed by worse options (e.g. WOFF is very lightweight, try that first, then fall back on SVG fonts which are much bigger)

Try this:

```
/*Font Face*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SegoeUI-Light';
  src: url('segoeuilight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('segoeuilight.woff') format('woff'), url('segoeuilight.ttf') format('truetype'), url('segoeuilight.svg#segoeuilight') format('svg'); 
  font-weight: normal; 
  font-style: normal 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'SegoeUI';
  src: url('segoeui.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('segoeui.woff') format('woff'), url('segoeui.ttf') format('truetype'), url('segoeui.svg#segoeui') format('svg'); 
  font-weight: normal; 
  font-style: normal; 
}
```

**Edit** removing the double inclusion of the EOT format, shouldn't need it.

Comment: How should I do it? Can I get any help on this? Thanks

Comment: Updated, take a look.

Comment: Is this on a web server or not? If it's not, why not just install the font and then use `local("<fontname>")`?